# Errors of the definite integral term on the code

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

```
 δ = 10; ρ = 28; β = (8/3); x0 = -7; y0 = 0; z0 = 4;

s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == δ*(y[t] - x[t]), y'[t] == ρ*x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
             z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - β*z[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0},
            {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 50}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

 Plot[{x[t] /. s, y[t] /. s, z[t] /. s}, {t, 0, 10}, 
      AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]

p[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[δ ((y[tt] /. s) - (x[tt] /. s)), {tt, 0, t}, 
                             WorkingPrecision -> 16, AccuracyGoal -> 100]

q[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ρ (x[tt] /. s) - (y[tt] /. s) - (x[tt] /. s)*(z[tt] /. s), 
                             {tt, 0, t}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, AccuracyGoal -> 100]

w[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(x[tt] /. s)*(z[tt] /. s) - βz[tt] /. s, {tt, 0, t}, 
                             WorkingPrecision -> 16, AccuracyGoal -> 100]

res[t_] := (x[t] - x0) + (y[t] - y0) + (z[t] - z0) - (p[t] + q[t] + w[t]);

Plot[Evaluate[RealExponent[res[t] /. s]], {t, 0, 4}, 
     PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0], RGBColor[2, 0, 0]}, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

I am trying  to generate the residual function graphs for Lorentz system but code has some errors on multiplication of function from definite integral term.

Comment: `\[Beta]z[tt]` is an undefined quantity.  Perhaps, you mean `\[Beta] z[tt]`.  With this correction, the code is painfully slow.

Comment: The definition of `w` is incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain literally the quantity requested in the question (with errors in `w` corrected) in a reasonable amount of time, use

```
Clear[x, y, z, p, q, w]
{x, y, z} = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == \[Delta]*(y[t] - x[t]), 
    y'[t] == \[Rho]*x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - \[Beta]*z[t], 
    x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

to determine `{x, y, z}` essentially as in the question, and then use `NDSolve` again but with higher precision to determine `{p, q, w}` quickly.

```
{p, q, w} = NDSolveValue[{p'[t] == \[Delta] (y[t] - x[t]), 
    q'[t] == \[Rho] x[t] - y[t] - x[t]*z[t], w'[t] == x[t]*y[t] - \[Beta] z[t], 
    p[0] == 0, q[0] == 0, w[0] == 0}, {p, q, w}, {t, 0, 10}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxSteps -> 100000];

res[t_] := (x[t] - x0) + (y[t] - y0) + (z[t] - z0) - (p[t] + q[t] + w[t]);
Plot[Evaluate[RealExponent[res[t]]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, "res"}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey much appreciated

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you try to solve an ode-system and plot the residual?

If so, there is no need to define `p[t],...`!

Try

```
Clear[x, y, z]
{x, y, z} =NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == \[Delta]*(y[t] - x[t]), 
y'[t] == \[Rho]*x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - \[Beta]*z[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
z[0] == z0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 50} ];

Plot[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 50}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Now plot the three residuals

```
Plot[Evaluate[ {x'[t] == \[Delta]*(y[t] - x[t]),y'[t] == \[Rho]*x[t] - y[t] -x[t] z[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - \[Beta]*z[t]} /. Equal -> Subtract], {t, 0,50}, PlotRange-> {-.01, .01}]
```

[image]

That's it!

Comment: Thanks Ulrich the idea is not to plot individual residuals. The idea is to plot the sum of those three  residual function

Comment: Ok, it is no problem to easy modify the plot and sum the Abs of the individual residuals. One point I want to note is your definition of `res[t]=..`. If NIntegrate works without error, you get `p[t]=x[t],q[t]=y[t],w[t]=z[t]` and `res==x0+y0+z0` is the sum of initial conditions. Curios! In my answer the residual is the error obtained by substituting the solution of NDSolve into the ode.